# Querying posts from a different page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a website for a church, and I wanna display JUST one staff profile from the staff page on the home page. On the staff page I used Advanced Custom Field to add staff profile. And it has img, title, name and description field.

At the end of the code. "home-staff-wrapper" is where I wanna display one staff profile from the staff page. Please help!!

This is my home page code:

```
<?php
    /* page-homepage.php */
    get_header();
?>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="home-slider-wrapper">
        <?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider('homepageslider'); }?>
        <div id="home-church-intro">
            <div id="home-intro-content"><?php the_field('church_intro'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home-left-content-wrapper">
        <div id="home-worship-time-wrapper">
            <div id="home-title">Worship Time</div>
            <div id="home-worship-detail">
                <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="home-announcement-wrapper">
            <div id="home-title">Announcement</div>
            <div id="home-announcement-detail"><?php the_field('announcement'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home-right-content-wrapper">
        <div id="home-sermon-wrapper">
            <div id="home-title">Sermon</div>
            <?php $sermon_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 2)); ?>
            <?php if($sermon_query -> have_posts()): while($sermon_query -> have_posts()): $sermon_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <div id="home-sermon-detail">
                <div id="home-sermon-thumbnail-wrapper">
                    <div id="home-sermon-thumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
                </div>
                <div id="home-sermon-title-and-date-wrapper">
                    <div id="home-sermon-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div id="home-sermon-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="home-staff-wrapper">
            <?php //$staff = new WP_Query('page_id = 273'); ?>
            <?php //while($staff -> have_posts()): ?>
            <?php //the_post(); ?>
            <?php //the_content(); ?>
            <?php //endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to display one specific staff's profile or a random one?

Comment: I want to display one specific staff's profile.

Comment: Can you get the entire staff showing up in that section?  If so, can you change the line saying `the_post();` to only show the name?

Comment: I couldn't get the staff page to display on my home page. The new WP_Query should get that page, but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: How about `new WP_Query(array('page_id' => 273));` ?

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for replying. I used the new WP_Query and able to get the content from the staff page but not the img, title, name, and description from the Advanced Custom Field Repeater. I've changed the condition logic from ACF to display the staff on home page but still no luck. Thank you again for helping me. :)